# Как разбить CollectionView на страницы?

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, uikit

Есть горизонтальный CollectionView.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать "страницы", как показано ниже на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, мне нужно чтобы на экране были страницы(ячейки) и при их перелистывании, у меня не могло быть промежуточного результата(грубо говоря, либо 1 страница, либо 2 и тд).

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то вас необходимо это yourCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли! А то я уже начал пользоваться PageControl + View, а в моем случае это не особо подходит ;)